# Is it safe to share a .ovpn file?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

My Asus router comes with a OpenVPN server, the router exports a configuration file .ovpn for importing on the client. Looking at the contents of that file I can see there's a Private Key in there, so then I wonder:

1. Will all clients have the same Private Key? Thus the same encryption?
2. Is it safe to share the .ovpn file with everyone that should have access to my VPN?
3. If a device was stolen, then I would have to reconfigure all the other devices with a new .ovpn file?
4. Are there any best practices around all of this?

Comment: How do you know it is a private key? Is it an actual key or just a fingerprint to allow a client to verify it is connecting to the right server? There is an example client file at https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/ at a minimum it would be worth seeing a redacted version of the file you are looking at with personal information replaced.

Comment: I know it's a private key because it says PRIVATE KEY

Comment: @Mokubai: OpenVPN does allow inline specification of certificates and keys inside the .conf / .ovpn file, and I've seen that in configurations generated by various "appliance"-type setups.

Comment: Yeah, looking through the howto page I linked does actually mention sharing a secret key (mentioned under "static key") before hand and suggests that it is intended for a single client and server and as a result isn't entirely secure in that way. https://openvpn.net/community-resources/static-key-mini-howto/

Comment: It can also apply to HMAC auth keys which are used _on top_ of regular certificate-based authentication, and to the regular per-user certificates as well.

Comment: We do not share router configurations (router VPN configurations) with anyone. The VPN section will have a user setup section to set up users with access

Comment: The VPN setup section has an area for adding users, but the .ovpn file that same section exports contains a Private Key. I need the .ovpn file and the username and password in order to connect.

Answer (score 0):

> Will all clients have the same Private Key?

Ideally, no. Each client *should* have its own certificate, and each certificate *should* have a unique private key. If I remember correctly, standard OpenVPN configuration even enforces a maximum of 1 connection per client name (although this can be disabled).

So although a single certificate shared by multiple clients is technically possible, it's very much not recommended.

> Thus the same encryption?

These certificates are not used for encryption – they're used for *authentication.* The per-session encryption key is generated independently from that.

> Is it safe to share the .ovpn file with everyone that should have access to my VPN?

That's practically the same question as "Is it safe to share the username and password?" And usually, no, *you wouldn't* let multiple different clients use the same username, because then it becomes very difficult to protect the credentials from leaking where they shouldn't and revoke them when that happens.

There are exceptions to this, e.g. multiple devices owned by the *same* client could use the same account (whether it's by username or by certificate), but as a general rule, primary credentials should never be shared between users.

(Secondary credentials, such as OpenVPN's HMAC "tls-auth" static key, serve a different purpose and sharing them between users is usually okay and sometimes unavoidable.)

Comment: The Router's OpenVPN server configuration page allows me to add users but I also need to download the .ovpn file. On my OpenVPN Android App I need to enter the .ovpn file and then provide my username and password. I have 3 users configured, all of them with different passwords, but they will all have the same .ovpn file as the router only has one "Export" button that generates one file.